# Can we create or fetch database names in Google CloudSQL using their Java SDK?

Tags: java, mysql, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-platform

I want to fetch all the names of tables present in a database, which is present in a Google CloudSQL instance. Is this possible through their Java Client libraries (Java SDK).

I know 'gcloud (command line)' can be used, but I want to do every call using Java APIs. Please help. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. You can enable MySQL Connector/J in your Java App Engine application:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/#enable_connector_j

Connect and communicate with your database. Check this document:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/